# How can i create an specific route using resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create this route, i need pass arbitrary_id and `api/v2`

`/api/v2/arbitrary/:arbitrary_id/sort_games`

this is the route, i using resources:

`resources :arbitrary do get 'api/v2/sort_games', to: 'arbitrary#sort' end`

i am trying to indicate api/v2 as static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v2 do
    get '/arbitrary/:arbitrary_id/sort_games', to: 'arbitrary#sort_games'
  end
end
```

This route isn’t really RESTful and doesn’t match the `resources` pattern (`/arbitrary/...` should be plural; you’d need to add that to the `inflections.rb` file).